# NGINX Caching Symlinked Web Site Location

Tags: php, nginx, php-deployer

I have this weird issue that was not happening before.

I am running a Ubuntu Box on Digital Ocean that uses NGINX and PHP-FPM. I also use PHP Deployer to deploy code between Stage and Prod.

Deployer uses symlinks to tell the server where the files are in this case `/var/www/mydommain.com/current` would be the symlink that points to `/var/www/mydomain.com/releases/26`.

That is all good and if I do `cd /var/www/mydomain.com/current` it will change to `releases/26`. The website however is still pointing to `releases/25`. I have restarted NGINX and PHP-FPM multiple time without success.

Why is NGINX still pointing to `releases/25` when the symlink actually points to `releases/26`? I can't get it.

In NGINX config for this domain I have `root /var/www/mydomain.com/current`

Comment: Did you try in a incognito browser with no cache?

Comment: Yeah. that did not work. It finally fixed itself and I am not sure what did it. Probably a combination of restarts. Also I had to shorten .dep/releases by manually removing old/no longer needed releases from the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an 8 months old question, but this might help others:

I ran into the same issue and noticed that if I edit my index file (index.php) of the ***previous*** release, the symlink is magically refreshed.

After deploying, I simply run:

`touch /path/to/releases/[previous_release_number]/public_html/index.php`

...to update the file's modification timestamp.

I ended up including it in my `deploy:symlink` task like this:

```
task('deploy:symlink', function () {
    run("cd {{deploy_path}} && ln -sfn {{release_path}}/public_html ./public_html");
    run("touch {{previous_release}}/public_html/index.php");
})->desc('Linking latest version to public_html'); // <= Added this
```

Hope this helps.
Regards, Wouter

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to `$document_root` in your Nginx configuration being cached until you do `sudo service php5.6-fpm restart`.

You can replace `$document_root` with `$realpath_root` to avoid the caching.

This website helped me:

https://joshtronic.com/2019/07/29/symlinks-with-nginx-and-php-fpm/